# Promise that doesn't catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I was doing some Prisma requests and I noticed that some Promises weren't working.

I know I could use async-await, but this should work.

```
prisma
  .user({ uid })
  .then(user => {
    if (Object.keys(user).length) throw 'error!'

    return prisma.updateUser({
      data: { money: user.money - 50 },
      where: { id: user.id }
    })
  })
  .then(user => {
    prisma
      .createLog({
        user: { connect: { id: user.id } },
        type: 'TICKET_BOUGHT',
        date: new Date()
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Ticket bought'))
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

If the user doesn't exist, it should throw an error, but instead the second 'then' is run.

Comment: Does it by any chance throw an error when a user does exist?

Comment: No, I've already test it

Comment: Ok, now this is wierd: the first 'then' isn't even run

Comment: @JuanM04 expose your user(param) function...

Comment: @EugeneSunic is a Prisma function. It gets an user of a database. https://prisma.io

Comment: @JuanM04 is there a possibility to test your code somewhere online?

Comment: As fas as I know, no

Comment: well, could you put an effort to somehow put it online?

Comment: Well... When I've tested online, it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if (!Object.keys(user).length) throw 'error!'
```

Comment: A brief explanation has a lot more value than *"try this"* which is virtually meaningless

Comment: I'm testing and, don't ask me why, nothing works

Comment: the please expose your .user({ uid }) promise

Answer (score 0):

`if (Object.keys(user).length) throw 'error!'` that's mean if user exists, because `object.keys` function will return array list of object keys `.length` checking array length,

so if user exists ? Object.keys will return array list of user properties, that's mean length will be greater than zero and if condition will be true so throw will run,

If user not exist `Object.keys` will return zero and `if(0)` equal false so the throw will not run

In your case you should check `if(   !   Object.keys(user).length )` or `if( Object.keys(user).length === 0 )` or you can check `if( !user || user == {} )` or  `if( !user || !user.uid)` instead of uid  you can change it to any required property and you are sure 100% this property will return in all cases